# javascript - if else statement that uses document.getElementsByClassName with three possible scenarios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am currently feeling my way through simple javascript tasks, i am trying to put together an if/else statement in javascript that check the h1 on my page to see if one of possibly three classes exist, after the javascript determines which class is attached to the h1 i need it to pushes out a specific text into the h1.

the script i am tinkering with is     document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle_contact")[0].innerHTML = "sample text 1";

i have three possible class names:
pagetitle_home
pagetitle_about
pagetitle_contact

help is much appreciated, if more info is needed let me know :(

thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do? You want to display some content in an HTML element, if that HTML element exists with a given class name?

Comment: i have h1 text i am trying to replace

<a href="#"><h1 class='pagetitle_home'><span>text to replace</span></h1></a>

depending on what page i am on, i am using the class to change the h1 text with javascript, my website is only three pages, a home, about and a contact page. so if i am on the about page i need the h1 text to display a specific text different than that of the other pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("first_class");
if (elements.length) {
    elements[0].innerHTML = "first text";
} else {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("second_class");
    if (elements.length) {
        elements[0].innerHTML = "second text";
    } else {
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName("third_class");
        if (elements.length) { // can be left out if the presence of one of the three classes is guaranteed
            elements[0].innerHTML = "third text";
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice that it will only modify one of those elements, since we're using if/then/else. If you want to modify the first element of **all** these classes, you just need 3 if/then :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("first_class");
if (elements.length) {
    elements[0].innerHTML = "first text";
}
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("second_class");
if (elements.length) {
    elements[0].innerHTML = "second text";
}
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("third_class");
if (elements.length) {
    elements[0].innerHTML = "third text";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, unfortunately there will only ever be a singular class in my html (first_class, second_class or third_class) all three are not present on the page, i need the javascript to verify which class is being used on in the html and push the correct text into the h1 because the other two classes will not be there

Comment: @AronLilland well I fail to see what's unfortunate then, that's what my first snippet does.

Comment: you are correct, i have some conflicts in my javascript i need to work out, ran your code in jfiddle and it works, its not working on my browser though, ill keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle for you . Check it

https://jsbin.com/lecuro/edit?html,js,output

```
<div class="pagetitle_contact"></div>

<div class="pagetitle_home"></div>

<div class="pagetitle_about"></div>
```

JS

```
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle_contact").length) {

  document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle_contact")[0].innerHTML = "sample text 1";

}
if (document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle_home").length) {

  document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle_home")[0].innerHTML = "sample text 2";

}
if (document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle_about").length) {

  document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle_about")[0].innerHTML = "sample text 3";

}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, unfortunately there will only ever be a singular class in my html (first_class, second_class or third_class) all three are not present on the page, i need the javascript to verify which class is being used on in the html and push the correct text into the h1 because the other two classes will not be there

Answer (score 0):

If you call `document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS_NAME").length` and there are no DOM elements with that class name, it will return 0.

`document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS_NAME")` will return an HTMLCollection, which is *almost* like an array, so you'll just do:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS_NAME");  // Get every element with that class name
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)  // Iterate over every single element in the collection
    elements[i].innerHTML = "Text to be inserted";  // Alter the HTML inside the current element
```

That will alter the inner HTML mark-up of every element with the specified class name, just change `"CLASS_NAME"` to the name of your class.

[Full code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8p9nsd1L/3/)

Answer (score 0):

As a general recommendation, there should be exactly one h1 tag on your page. So why don't you query that single h1 tag, and then query which CSS class is attach to it?

Comment: there is only 1 h1 on the page, i need to query which class is written to the h1, i wasn't able to explain correctly =/